# Nav changes size on index.html

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, nav

I'm using the Bootstrap navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="who.html"><img src="../img/RP.png" id="brand-img"/></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">WHO <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="what.html">WHAT</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="how.html">HOW</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Yet when I switch to pages what.html and how.html, the nav becomes slightly smaller. When I renamed index.html to who.html, I stopped seeing this bug. Any ideas?

Comment: The HTML file name doesn't have any bearing on the layout. As long as the HTML file links to the correct CSS files.Maybe the browser was zoomed in?

Comment: Yes, that's why I was confused. Turns out when I put it up on a server the problem went away...guess it will remain a mystery